# Ruby library not found (no such file to load)

Tags: ruby

I manually placed a library in the library directory (/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8) and when I try to require it, it says "no such file to load".

I used "$:.first" to get the library path, so why wont it work? Is there any good way to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you copy and paste the contents of `$:`, the full path to your library and the require call, just so we have all the cards on the table? That eliminates any chance of error on your part leading you to report things incorrectly. (No insult meant to you — it's just a very common culprit in "mysterious" cases like this.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the problem. The library (fsevents) was calling "osx/foundation" and the machine that had the problem didn't have RubyCocoa installed. After I installed RubyCocoa it worked perfectly. It's just strange that it said that it couldn't find fsevents.rb when the problem was actually with osx/foundation.

And to answer your questions, the value of $: for me is: "=> ["/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8", "/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9", "/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8", "/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9", "/opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8", "/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9", "."]"

Answer (score 0):

A couple of shots in the dark:

- are you using lower case in your require statements?  If you're on a unix system, case matters.
- did you try restarting your terminal?

Comment: The case is correct and I restarted the terminal. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Another shot in the dark... Is the file readable (i.e. the current user has read access)? Ruby gives the same error message if a file does not exist or if it is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Joining in with the stabbing in the dark… :)

Did you put a directory or a .rb-file in the load path? If you put a directory, did you try to load a file in the directory?

A lot of libraries put all their files in a directory of their own, but also give you a single .rb in the "root" of the path with the same name as the directory. That file in turn load all files needed in the directory.